# Values in more than one row

Tags: python, pandas

[Here is a link to csv](https://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/2249131---ixre.html)

I have a dirty csv that looks like this:

[image]

I want to have a clean dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [ 1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['Harry', 'Hermiona', 'James'],
    'surname': ['Potter', 'Granger', 'Bond'],
    'grade': ['excellent', 'fabulous', 'fantastic'],
    'info3': ['something', None, None]
})
```

I am trying to think of a way to go to the next line to look for values, unless the first value in the csv row is a number

Comment: please provide a reproducible format for your input csv (**text**)

Comment: OP it's highly likely that because your input is so strange, you're likely to get answers which are particular to the sample input you received. I just wanted to make sure you know that, in case someone (ahem) posts an answer which works with the sample but not the real

Comment: also, based on your input, the last value in the 5th column should be "some irrelevent info"

Comment: To add along with Mark's point, the dirty data could be in any format (structure) and it is highly unlikely to predict the actual structure (unless you have a fixed structure/columns and data format and thus preventing to create a proper dataframe from it. And like mozway said please provide a csv file if possible so that we can try figuring out a way to parse the data and convert it into a valid structured dataframe

Comment: I don't think you can work with data like this. What's to say you won't get a row like `4,dajnkasjdnqlwk.dxmsw` that's not actually data...

Comment: I know my input is strange, but I want to try to clean it up as much as possible,

Comment: Screening lines one by one (so with e.g. `file.readlines()` method, NOT `pd.read_csv`...) I suppose you could start with recognizing *new person* lines with a regular expression, like `"^(\d),(\w+),(\w+)"`, then grab lines in between as information related to the current new person line. Getting all [id, name, surname, *whatever in between*] would be one obvious milestone in cleaning this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this file structure, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

with open('testcsv.csv') as fp:
    records = []
    s = ''
    for row in fp:
        if ',' in row:
            row = row.strip().replace(';', '')
            if row[0].isdigit():
                records.append(s.rstrip(','))
                s = row
            else:
                s += row
    records.append(s)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(records)))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id       name   surname       grade       info3
0   1      Harry    Potter   excellent   something
1   2   Hermiona   Granger    fabulous         NaN
2   3      James      Bond   fantastic         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

csv_file = """\
dsfsdlkfnsd;;
sdfsdfnlkdsfl;;
dsfsd;fmds;lfm
id, name, surname, grade, info3;;
1, Harry, Potter,;;
excellent, ;;
something,;;
2, Hermiona, Granger,;;
fabulous,,;;
3, James, Bond, fantastic,;;
some irrelevant info;;"""

header, lines = None, []
for line in csv_file.splitlines():
    line = line.strip(";").split(",")
    if not header and len(line) == 5:
        header = line
    if line and line[0].isnumeric():
        lines.append(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*zip_longest(*lines)), columns=header)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  id       name   surname       grade  info3
0  1      Harry    Potter               None
1  2   Hermiona   Granger               None
2  3      James      Bond   fantastic
```